# how to update my fragment from a thread in newInstance function?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-fragments, android-broadcast

in my `newInstance` i am going to create a thread then copy a file from a external storage in to internal storage and processing on it. after that i want to inform my fragment to update. how can i do this?

first: there is no `context` so i can not call `broadcast` inside my `thread`.

second: there is no activity yet `getActivity is null` because `onCreate` method has not been called, so `runOnUiThread` dose not work.

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {

    public static PageFragment newInstance(int pageNumber){

            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(EXTRA_PAGENUMBER, pageNumber);
            PageFragment fragment = new PageFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(args);

            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                // call fragment to update
            }).start();

            return fragment;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }
}
```

Comment: cant u pass Activity reference to ur newInstance method??

Comment: From where you calling this fragment??

Comment: @AvinashKumarPankaj from an activiy !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope at the time of calling fragment you must be calling this

```
PageFragment fragment = PageFragment.newInstance(pageNumber);
```

simply change it to

```
PageFragment fragment = PageFragment.newInstance(pageNumber, YourActivity.this);
```

In PageFragment you'll get your Activity's reference

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {

    public static PageFragment newInstance(int pageNumber, Context ctx){

            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(EXTRA_PAGENUMBER, pageNumber);
            PageFragment fragment = new PageFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(args);

            final Context context = ctx;

            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                // use ctx here
            }).start();

            return fragment;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to get the instance if the `Activity` in the on `onAttached()` callback. Do not start your background thread until the `onResume()` of your `Fragment` had been called. Before that time your fragment is not in a running state.

Comment: i have to start my thread as soon as possible because it will provide image for fragment so i do not want my user to wait.

Comment: You could start a thread or a loader in your activity to populate an image cache and your fragment load from that; if the cache doesn't have the image loaded yet it could start the load and notify your fragment when done.

Comment: `You could start a thread or a loader in your activity to populate an image cache` which images am i going to load when i do not know which fragment with page number is going to display.

Comment: The alternative is to use an image cache and loader kicked off by the fragment in its `onResume()`. Then you are back to your original concern. You may be able to get away with triggering the load (thread) once the activity is attached, but you are really only saving a small amount of time. You'll definitely need to watch your interactions between threads and the lifecycle of your fragment and/or activity.